# Literature now has a community-maintained Twitter account!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Like [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1798/5323) and some other sites, Literature now has a community-maintained [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackLiterature)! This account is not run by SE robots; [Stack Exchange stopped doing that some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/266359).

At this point, the account is run by me; however, you can still get involved! (Please do!) Here are some things that you can do to help promote our site outside of the Stack Exchange network:

- Follow, like, and retweet us, of course!
- Tweet questions from your own accounts (make sure to tag us by including `@StackLiterature`* in the message -- there's a fair chance of a retweet in there for you `:-)`) using the [nifty share link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63686/266359) underneath posts (or the share button, in the apps). If you use those links, you're also eligible for the Announcer family of badges.
- Give us constructive feedback on our tweets via Twitter or in our [Twitter suggestions chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57497/literature-tweet-suggestions).

We're also experimenting with tweets from chat in [another chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57503/twitter-control-room); ping myself or Hamlet in [The Reading Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room) to get access.

Let's try to get this site some more attention on the greater internets!

---

*I realize that this nomenclature is [not preferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295012/266359); I created the account before I saw that MSE post. [We're trying to figure out a suitable replacement](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36864952#36864952); can you suggest some?

Comment: #woohoo! #yay! #hashtagsarestupid!

Comment: I also found [Literature SE](https://twitter.com/StackLit), which has not tweeted since 2012. Was this account linked to an earlier Lit SE site?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Yes, that was the infamous [Lit.1](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/913/17), which existed at a time when SE sites came with official Twitter accounts and were shut down if not active enough. IIRC, our mods asked SE if it'd be possible for them to take control of that old Twitter account and were told no.

Answer (score 5):

Woohoo! Thank you for setting this up; I was [planning on doing it myself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=36801674#36801674), but you got to it first ;)

However, I'd recommend documenting exactly how this works.

- *Who* exactly can post tweets in the control room?
- What are the requirements for a message to get tweeted?
- Who do I contact to get access?
- any other such questions.

---

Handy links:
**[Twitter Control Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57503/twitter-control-room)**
**[Tweet Suggestions Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57497/literature-tweet-suggestions)**
**[@StackLiterature on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackLiterature)**

Comment: Good ideas, all. I'm *extremely* busy right now IRL, but I plan to work on some of those things over the next few days.