# Best Questions & Answers from 1st Quarter of 2021

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in the [regular best-of-quarter collections](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), intended to gather some particularly good Literature Q&A in order to get some easily available links to showcase our site.

One use for this post could be to gather links for promotion on Literature's [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17). But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the first quarter (Jan/Feb/Mar) of 2021**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. The date of the meta answer doesn't matter - late entries are still more than welcome! - only the date of the post on the main site that's being nominated.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed these two answers because the writers put in a lot of research to answer the difficult questions asked:

- bobble's painstakingly detailed [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/17661/289) to Randal'Thor's question "[How long does the story of Watership Down take?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17343/289)"
- Laurel's terrific detective work in the [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/17364/289) to HeyJude's request to [identify a Middle English poem](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17188/289).

As for questions, I must confess that I'm picking these two because I like delving into English Renaissance Literature and so working on the answers was fun. Both were from new contributors:

- Busstop Boxer's question, [Political Allegory in *The Shepheardes Calendar*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18138/289)
- Luxury Mode's question, [What is the “manhood of a Roman recovery” in John Milton's Areopagitica?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17647/289)

I also found this as yet unanswered question interesting because it's very specific, asking about the change of a single letter in the text of a poem:

- ruffle's question, [When and how was the phrase “these dark Satanic mills” in Blake's “Jerusalem” first altered to “those dark Satanic mills”?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17926/289)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to highlight two newer contributors (one joined this quarter, one has a single older answer but earned most of their reputation this quarter):

- **indigochild** posted [five nice answers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/12002/indigochild?tab=answers) in February, all nicely detailed and well-researched. Most of them were to older unanswered questions, resulting in four Revival badges, while the last one (actually their first answer on the site) hit the [HNQ jackpot](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/17394/17).
- **b4rtr** posted [four nice answers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A10619+created%3A2021-01..2021-03) this quarter, again well researched with sources, links, and quotes. Most of them were to older unanswered questions, resulting in three Revival badges, including [two](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/70/17) to [questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1970/17) from the very first quarter of this site's existence, back in 2017.

The quarterly reputation leagues were once again [dominated](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/668/quarter/literature/2021-01-01) by **verbose**, who posted [more answers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-01..2021-03+user%3A289) than anyone else during the quarter (total 90 making an average of exactly one per day). It's hard to nominate a favourite, but I have to give a shout-out to his massive essay on the Ur-Hamlet, answering my question [How has knowledge of the Ur-Hamlet evolved over the centuries?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16889/17) on the very first day of 2021.