# Best Questions & Answers from 3rd Quarter of 2022

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in the [regular best-of-quarter collections](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), intended to gather some links to particularly good Literature Q&A for showcasing our site.

One use for this post could be to gather links for promotion on Literature's [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17). But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the third quarter (Jul/Aug/Sep) of 2022**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. Some of them still have no answers, and late entries are always welcome, as long as the nominated main-site post is within the required period.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Comment: [Query for answers submmited during July-September 2022](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2022-07..2022-09).

Answer (score 3):

Charo contributed a few answers about medieval Italian literature, e.g.

- to the question [Why the phrasing "where the sun is silent" in Dante's "Inferno"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/23058/2191) and
- to the question [Meaning and significance of "cacheremo" in the Decameron?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/22903/2191).

I failed to answer the question [Was Whitman the first poet to write in sentence fragments?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/22917/2191) but Peter Shor [found an earlier example](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/22918/2191).

Answer (score 2):

I found quite interesting [Quassnoi's answer about Eugène Sue's text used as a source of inspiration in a M. Joly book](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/22905/10143). This fact is indeed mentioned in Umberto Eco's book *Six Walks in the Fictional Woods*, but it's not clear at all which Sue's work has been used by M. Joly and this isn't easy to find. So I think Quassnoi did a good job researching.