# Best Questions & Answers from 4th Quarter of 2022

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest instalment in the [regular best-of-quarter collections](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), intended to gather some links to particularly good Literature Q&A for showcasing our site.

One use for this post could be to gather links for promotion on Literature's [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17). But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - for example, if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the fourth quarter (Oct/Nov/Dec) of 2022**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. Some of them still have no answers, and late entries are always welcome, as long as the nominated main-site post is within the required period.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Just within the time-frame (11th of October) I'd like to nominate a very nice three-way collaboration: [Trying to find a poem called "The Boaster"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/trying-to-find-a-poem-called-the-boaster/23282#23282). The quest began with Rand al'Thor finding a reference in an old and dusty BBC discussion forum. I picked up the thread and traced the music to an advertisement on eBay, and finally Gareth Rees located the original Czech folksong. It was a lovely example of people working together, and wresting clues from the most improbable of places.

Answer (score 3):

This was going to be an "excellent new user" answer, but then I realised that her previous posts were in 2021. Anyway, [Alice](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/12320/alice) posted a great answer to [What's the term for multiple levels of reality in a fictional work?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23508/17)

While searching through my own appreciative comments from the last quarter, I found several excellent answers from [Clara Diaz Sanchez](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11734/clara-diaz-sanchez), including to a couple of questions that I'd tried to answer with less success: [Has there ever been a stage production of Chapter 15 of Ulysses?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23299/17) and [What did Lem find in his game-theoretical analysis of the writings of Marquis de Sade?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23449/17)

Late edit to this meta answer (after some upvotes already happened), but I also want to highlight new user [Lewis 010](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17541/lewis-010), who provided several great answers in November 2022, showing deep insight into the history of literature: [Origin of "The bells! The bells!" quote](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/23558/17) and [Was it so unusual for the time for Journey's End to have no leading lady?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/23561/17) and [When did detective fiction become primarily about murder?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/23564/17) are all worth highlighting.