# Best Questions & Answers from 2nd Quarter of 2023

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in the [regular best-of-quarter collections](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), the purpose of which is to gather some particularly good Literature Q&A in order to get some easily available links to showcase our site.

One use for this post could be to gather links for promotion on Literature's [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17). But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the second quarter (Apr/May/Jun) of 2023**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. The date of the meta answer doesn't matter - late entries are still more than welcome! - only the date of the post on the main site that's being nominated.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Comment: "Literature's community-run Twitter account" -> "Literature's community-run X account"? Doesn't have the same ring, though.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Thrower's question [How can the one-eyed Cyclops have multiple brows?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24724/289) was a genuine puzzler, and the accompanying illustration was marvelous. AlexG's [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/24783/289) to said question was well-argued and well-supported by reference to both primary and secondary sources. I believe it was this user's first answer on the site; quite an impressive début.

AlexG's second [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/24924/289), about Milton's citation of the Book of Malachi, was equally impressive in its scholarship and lucidity. Its navigation of the various possible readings of the passage in Malachi, and its explanation of how different Reformation factions adopted different readings, illuminates both the specific passage in Milton's text and the broader historical context.

Comment: thank you for your kind words!

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed reading [Can a ceiling have a front door that had once been a front door?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24707/can-a-ceiling-have-a-front-door-that-had-once-been-a-front-door).

It received four excellent answers, all of which insightfully interpreted Milne's dainty, clever 'joke'. (Which I didn't understand at first, so not only was it interesting, it was also useful.)